# Ubuntu 18.04 desktop bug - location services cannot be disabled?

Tags: desktop-environments, bug-reporting, system-settings, privacy, geolocation

I recently noticed that, despite location services being disabled in the settings menu, the location service indicator will sometimes show in the upper right corner. When I navigate to the settings -> privacy settings the location service option will say "In Use" despite being "Off".

How can I find out which app specifically is using the location services, and how can I stop location services from being used under these circumstances?

Thanks!